# Receiving and Convert JSON data to Java Object

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to store `"data"` Data :

```
{
"api_status": 200,
"data": [ 

{"id": "755", "post_id": "755", "publisher": { "username": "test1", "email": "test1@gmail.com"}},
{"id": "765","post_id": "765","publisher": { "username": "test2", "email": "test2@gmail.com"}}

]
}
```

I created this to receive data
**ModelPost.java**

```
public class ModelPost {

    Integer api_status ;
    List<Data> data ;
}
```

**Data.java**

```
public class Data {

    String id, post_id, postText;
    Publisher publisher;

}
```

**Publisher.java**

```
public class Publisher {

    String username, email;

}
```

The problem is in the ModelPost.java file when the data type is `List<Data> data ;` an error occurs but when I type `List<Any> data ;` instead of `List<Data> data ;` I can receive the data but the data is a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: `when the data type is List<Data> data; an error occurs` can you [edit] the question and tell us what error you are getting?